# Scraping with BeautifulSoup, but first have to input values?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to web scraping and am not very familiar with requests and BeautifulSoup.

I am trying to scrape an aspx website with BeautifulSoup. But to get the values I want to scrape, I first need to select a drop down value, input an ID, and then press submit.

Is this even possible?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) would be better for your use case

Comment: Can you share the URL and values you want to submit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to input the url that you get after you have made all the selections from dropdowns. Otherwise.. using Selenium is best bet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `selenium` is a powerful tool when working with these kind of websites, but it is not the only solution to your problem.

By the information you have provided in your question, I assume that the page in question provides a form, you are completing it by selecting the desired value(s) in the dropdown and then hitting the `submit` button.

If that's the case, then there is a `POST` request involved in the process (more information [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/)). You can easily check the requests data and then reproduce it using `python`.

Chrome users guide:

- Press F12 on the page in question. A developer console should appear.
- Go to the `network` tab and press CTRL+R
  [image]
- Check the `Preserve Log` and `Disable Cache` checkboxes in the upper left
  [image]
- Complete the form data with the needed information and press the `submit` button.
- Check the `Doc` or `Other` tabs for a `POST` request
  [image]
- Scroll down on the request's window until you find the `Form Data` section[image]
- That's the data you need to replicate. Most probably, the selected dropdown value is among them.
- Now the `python` part

```py
import requests

url = 'https://formsmarts.com/html-form-example'  # extract the URL from the <form> tag
data = {
   'u_omM_4607': 'John',
   'u_omM_338354': 'Doe',
   'u_omM_4608': 'john.doe@email.com',
   'u_omM_338367': 'Support Inquiry',   # this was from a dropdown
   'u_omM_4609': 'No comments'
}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)    # send a POST request with the completed data
print(r.text)                        # r.text is the HTML information of the response which can be scraped at your own will
```

Hopefully this at least answers a bit of your questions. Feel free to reply with extra questions if needed.